# How to let Selenium Driver resolve hostname to another ip?

Tags: selenium

Currently our tests have a specific hostname in the url (eg. `http://foo.bar/whatever`)

We want to resolve `foo.bar` to a different IP when running the tests.

Manually we would do this by changing the host file or using this piece of c# code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ip-of-foobar/whatever");
request.Host = "foo.bar";
```

We need to have the correct hostname... maybe there is another way setting request headers in Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, there is NO API in selenium to set the IP of the server you want to open the browser. `get()` takes the URL which contains the domain name or IP address. you can not set the value as you set using `C#` libraries.

As you want to change the domain name to IP address, following are the two options available:

1. Keep the IP address in a file. Use the `language libraries` to read the value from the file and set it to a `variable`. Use that variable wherever you are referencing the URL. example: `driver.get("http://"+variable+"/")` to get the home page.
2. Use the `test framework capabilities`. parameterization (`parameter` in `testng`, [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm)) or `data references`. This allows you to define the value outside the code and then refer the value using a variable name in the code. Same as the first option, but avoids File reading activity. During the run, change the value, so it will be reflected everywhere.

please let us know the language and framework you are using, so I can try to give the exact solution based on above options.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. What I am trying to do is make sure that the correct hostname is delivered in the requests while using the ip-address in the url OR use the hostname and make it resolve to a correct ip.

Comment: We need this scenario to be able to switch from one cluster to the other without bringing it down. Which means the live site has the same hostname as the one we want to test. We can probably solve this with infrastructure, but it would be nice to do this directly through Selenium. In fact I would just like to tell the browser which ip it should use for a certain hostname. Not sure if this is possible considering security.

Comment: As I said in the answer, there is NO API to tell which IP to use by the browser. The only way you can parameterize is take the IP/Host away from the code, i.e., from `driver.get()` method (put it in a file) and replace with a variable. so you can switch to the IP you want by setting the variable to the IP you want to hit (you can map server hostname -> IP address in the file).